# Calling aws lambda functions from iOS swift with Amplify

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

### Platform

Swift 4, iOS 13, Xcode 11. Using Amplify, GraphQL, Cognito

### Problem

I want to trigger an AWS lambda function called `onCall`. It has been written and is just a simple blank function. On the client side I am following [1] and have:

```
    let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()

    let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
        "key1" : "value1",
         "key2" : 2 ,
         "key3" : [1, 2],
         "isError" : false
    ]

    lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("onCall", jsonObject: jsonObject)
        .continueWith(block: {(task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if( task.error != nil) {
            print("Error: \(task.error!)")
            return nil
        }

        print(">> lambda \(task)")

        // Handle response in task.result
        return nil
    })
```

But I get a permission denied error:

Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSLambdaErrorDomain Code=0 "AccessDeniedException" UserInfo={StatusCode=403, responseStatusCode=403, responseHeaders={type = immutable dict, count = 5,
        entries =>
            2 : x-amzn-requestid = {contents = "83047425-06c6-4193-b5c6-ac8461d84aa0"}
            3 : Content-Length = 243
            4 : Content-Type = {contents = "application/json"}
            5 : x-amzn-errortype = {contents = "AccessDeniedException"}
            6 : Date = {contents = "Thu, 07 May 2020 02:18:00 GMT"}
        }
        , Message=User: arn:aws:sts::870560247484:assumed-role/amplify-alpha-alphaenv-123654-authRole/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:870560247484:function:onCall, responseDataSize=243, NSLocalizedFailureReason=AccessDeniedException}

I have this line in my awsconfiguration.json file

```
"LambdaInvoker" : {
  "Default" : {
       "Region": "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Now in the docs it says I should use Amplify API, but I cannot find any amplify API for triggering lambda, and the doc is very sparse beyond basic use cases.

## Acceptable solutions

1. Making the `lambdaInvoker` work as is, regardless of the statement about `Amplify`.
2. Point me or provide code example for calling lamdas in Amplify API

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-lambda.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please check if you created the lambda with proper Policy:

[From the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-ios-lambda.html#setup)

> **f.** Under Lambda function handler and role, select Create new role from template(s). Type a Role name. Select the **Policy template** named **Simple Microservice permissions**.

Comment: You also may use Gateway API and through him trigger the lambda. Meanwhile, I will try to find the missing policy.

Comment: I also tried lambda-role as a policy. same error message. Basically cognito account is not configured to invoke lambda functions from this territory.

Comment: what if you try to set the policy with "allow" action "invokeFunction" and set the principal:
`"Principal": { "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" }`.
Maybe it makes sense to drill in this direction

Comment: where would I specify that? In awsconfiguartion.json or in console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/ ?

Comment: You would need adjust the execution role of the lambda, which can be found in aws web console -> lambda -> tab Permissions

Comment: Yeah for some reason I do not see Permissions tab on mine. I there another way of doing this? Maybe my client side awsconfiguration.json file is not configured properly